# How could I make this DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() a thread safe one?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, file-handling

I want to generate file names using DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() but with multi threading I am getting the same filename for multiple threads which results in a I/O error writing the file.
I want to have each thread to have a separate file.

How could i achieve getting different filenames using DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() in C#?

Comment: You probably don't need multiple threads for it to go wrong - a single thread calling it fast enough could make it fail. Ignoring that, however: Is it allowable to add an affix to the filename, or must it be just a long?

Comment: Note that DateTime.Now is (generally) only updated around once every 50ms, so that's the window within which two threads could see the same time.

Comment: It is not allowed to add a affix and should only use the long value, even getting the datetime value by locking a object gets the same value for more than one thread

Comment: @VaseemAkram this is definitely an XY problem. You *assume* you can use `DateTime.Now` to generate unique file names, when that function is going to generate duplicates even if called by a *single* thread. Time after all doesn't care about a specific machine's threads, it's the same for everone (according to our current understanding at least). If you try to use *any* global status variable you *will* get duplicates from multiple threads. This isn't a thread safety issue. The value is what it is

Comment: @VaseemAkram what is your *actual* problem? What are you trying to do? Even if you used the CPU's high-performance tick count you could still get duplicates if two threads asked for it at the same time. Logging libraries solve this by using `Interlocked.Increment` to atomically increment and read a global counter in the same, atomic, step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the values of `DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()` in a tight loop, you will see results like this:

```
132453421456289289
132453421456289289
132453421456305151
132453421456312499
132453421456312499
132453421456312499
132453421456322499
132453421456322499
132453421456332746
132453421456342443
132453421456342443
132453421456352425
132453421456352425
132453421456362391
```

This tells us two things:

1. The returned values are repeated sometimes.
2. The smallest interval between values is around more than 1,000 (measured in 100ns units).

Since the actual precision of the time is much less than the units of precision of the time, we can safely solve this issue as follows:

Firstly, create an adjustment integer, initialised to zero. Then:

1. Convert the file time value to a multiple of 10,000. This does not
   lose significant precision.
2. If the file time to be returned is the same as a previous time, increment the adjustment.
3. Otherwise, set the adjustment back to zero.

For example:

```
public static class UniqueFileTime
{
    public static long Generate()
    {
        long next = 10_000 * (DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() / 10_000);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            next = Math.Max(next, _last);

            if (next == _last)
            {
                ++_adj;

                if (_adj == 10_000) // Broken!
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("UniqueFileTime.Generate() called too often.");
            }
            else
            {
                _adj  = 0;
                _last = next;
            }

            return next + _adj;
        }
    }

    static long _last;
    static int  _adj;
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

This implementation has minimal overhead, and the lock should be held only for extremely short periods.

It does mean that the precision of the file times is to the nearest 10,000 100-nanosecond units (since `ToFileTimeUtc()` returns a value in 100-nanosecond units). That's still a precision of 1 millisecond - more than enough for a file time for these purposes.

Here's a little test program to stress it:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var results = new List<List<long>>(1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            results.Add(new List<long>());

        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => getTimes(results[0]),
            () => getTimes(results[1]), 
            () => getTimes(results[2]),
            () => getTimes(results[3]),
            () => getTimes(results[4]),
            () => getTimes(results[5]),
            () => getTimes(results[6]),
            () => getTimes(results[7])
        );

        foreach (var time in results.SelectMany(r => r))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(time);
        }

        int distinctCount = results.SelectMany(r => r).Distinct().Count();

        if (distinctCount != 8000)
            Console.WriteLine("FAILED - Distinct should be 8000, but was " + distinctCount);
    }

    static void getTimes(List<long> times)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            times.Add(UniqueFileTime.Generate());
    }
}
```

This is really stressing it by creating 8 threads and getting unique times in a tight loop for each thread.

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the function in another function and use a semaphore to wait for a filename/datatime.

C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netcore-3.1

Java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: This won't solve the OP's problem. This isn't about thread-safety at all. Even a single thread would produce the same values if called in a tight loop